# Symmetric Universal Quantum Cloning Machine (UQCM) $N \to M$ for unknown states

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, cloning

Does it exist a schematic diagram of the quantum circuit implementing the symmetric UQCM $N \to M$ for unknown states? If yes, does anyone know a Qiskit implementation of it?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a [paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Flocks-of-Quantum-Clones%3A-Multiple-Copying-of-Bu%C5%BEek-Hillery/6f63c331c22179feaeefdbe88a599d365094acc7) which provides a circuit for the copying.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is not a circuit level description for $N \to M$ quantum cloning, of any type (e.g. universal, state dependent, etc).

However, here are three papers ([paper 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00125), [paper 2](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.10164), [paper 3](https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.15579)) which describe $1 \to M$ quantum telecloning circuits that are universal and symmetric. Quantum telecloning circuits require feed-forward operations. However, [quantum telecloning](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9806082) has the same properties as quantum cloning with respect to the quality of the clone qubits and the properties of the clones.